# Tkinter buttons are mixing with eachother

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know how to explain it but I have two different pages each with a certain number of buttons as grid

[Simple form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqD2H.jpg)

[Complex form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bwPN.jpg)

but when I select one of the radio buttons then select the other one after it gets mixed

[Chaos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqatZ.jpg)

Here is the code for making the grid

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os
import time, sys
from time import sleep

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
def changecolo(i, j):
    if not ((i == 0 and j == 0) or (i == 12 and j == 12)):
        if mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].cget('bg') == 'black':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].configure(bg = 'white')
        elif mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].cget('bg') == 'white':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].configure(bg = 'grey')
        elif mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].cget('bg') == 'grey':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row = i, column = j)[0].configure(bg = 'black')
def setalg():
    value = 6
def makegrid6():
    mFrame.grid_forget()
    makegrid66()
def makegrid66():
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range (6):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                grids6 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='blue', text = (5 - i) + (5 - j), state = 'disabled', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 11, height = 5)
                grids6.grid(row = i, column = j)
            elif i == 5 and j == 5:
                grids6 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='red', text = (5 - i) + (5 - j) , state = 'disabled',highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 11, height = 5)
                grids6.grid(row = i, column = j)
            elif (((i == 0 or i == 1 or i == 2) and (j == 2)) or (i == 4 and j == 1)):
                grids6 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='white', text = (5 - i) + (5 - j) , highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 11, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
                grids6.grid(row = i, column = j)
            elif (i == 3 and j == 2):
                grids6 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='grey', text = (5 - i) + (5 - j) , highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 11, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
                grids6.grid(row = i, column = j)
            else:
                grids6 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='black', text = (5 - i) + (5 - j), fg = 'white', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 11, height = 5, state = 'disabled')
                grids6.grid(row = i, column = j) 
    return mFrame.grid_slaves, i, j

def makegrid10():
    mFrame.grid_forget()
    makegrid100()
def makegrid100():
for i in range(13):
    for j in range (13):
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            grids10 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='blue', text = (12 - i) + (12 - j), fg = 'white', state = 'disabled', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 4, height = 2, command=lambda x = i, y = j: changecolo(x, y))
            grids10.grid(row = i, column = j)
        elif i == 12 and j == 12:
            grids10 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='red', text = (12 - i) + (12 - j), fg = 'white', state = 'disabled',highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 4, height = 2, command=lambda x = i, y = j: changecolo(x, y))
            grids10.grid(row = i, column = j)
        else:
            grids10 = tk.Button(mFrame, bg='black', text = (12 - i) + (12 - j), fg = 'white', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width = 4, height = 2, command=lambda x = i, y = j: changecolo(x, y))
            grids10.grid(row = i, column = j)
return mFrame.grid_slaves, i, j   

def play():
   if diffVar.get() == "sim":
       butons, l, k = makegrid66()
       Greedy(butons, l, k)
   else:
       butons, l, k = makegrid100()
       Greedy(butons, l, k)
def aStar():
   print(1000010)

def Greedy(butons, k, l):
    print(k, l)

def UCS():
    print(99)
mFrame = tk.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 500, bg = "lightgrey")
mFrame.place(x= 10, y = 10)

diffVar = tk.StringVar()
dif = tk.Label(root, text = "Problem Difficulty", bg = "Lightgrey")
dif.place (x = 550, y = 30)

simp = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Simple", value = "sim", bg = "Lightgrey", variable = diffVar, command = makegrid6)
simp.place(x = 550, y = 60)
comp = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Complex", value = "com", bg = "Lightgrey", variable = diffVar, command = makegrid10)
comp.place(x = 550, y = 90)

algVar = tk.IntVar()
algVar.set(1)
dif = tk.Label(root, text = "Choose an Algorithm", bg = "Lightgrey")
dif.place (x = 550, y = 180)

alg1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "A*", value = 1, bg = "Lightgrey", variable = algVar, command = setalg)
alg1.place(x = 550, y = 210)
alg2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Greedy", value = 2, bg = "Lightgrey", variable = algVar, command = setalg)
alg2.place(x = 550, y = 240)
alg3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "UCS", value = 3, bg = "Lightgrey", variable = algVar, command = setalg)
alg3.place(x = 550, y = 270)

playbu = tk.Button(root, text = "Play", bg = "White", width = 15, command = play)
playbu.place(x = 10, y = 550)

nextbu = tk.Button(root, text = "Next", bg = "White", width = 15)
nextbu.place(x = 140, y = 550)

fasterbu = tk.Button(root, text = "Faster", bg = "White", width = 15)
fasterbu.place(x = 270, y = 550)

resetbu = tk.Button(root, text = "Reset", bg = "White", width = 15)
resetbu.place(x = 400, y = 550)



root.mainloop()
```

is their any possible way that the buttons will resize themself in a way that they fit in the same size as the canvas, without me adjusting the width and the height of the button

Comment: to put widget on canvas you have to use `canvas.create_window(position, widget)`. not `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()`. Question is if you really need `Canvas` for this. Can't you put it in `Frame` and this `Frame` put directly in widow or page.

Comment: @furas I put it on a frame still the same problem

Comment: if you have problem with code then you have to show it. Not only code which you use to create grid but also code which you use to change elements in window. Maybe you have to remove old content before you put new elements. `Tkinter` doesn't remove old widgets when you put new widgets in the same place.

Comment: now when I watch your image with chaos I'm sure that problem is that you didn't remove old small buttons when you put new bigger buttons - `tkinter` will not do it automatically for you, you have to remove buttons on your own - ie. `grids10.grid_forget()` or `grids10.destroy()`. OR remove (or hide) canvas with old buttons and create new canvas and it will be empty.

Comment: I did try grid_forget and destroy with no success, I edited the post I put the whole code

Comment: put code again, select code and use button `{}` (or shortcut Ctrl+K) to correctly format code. Current code has wrong indentations and it can be useless.

Comment: it may not works because you don't keep access to buttons - you don't keep buttons on list - and `grids10` keep only last button. You have to do `grid_forget` with every button separatelly. Other problem is that to put on canvas you have to use `create_window`, not `grid`. If you use `grid then you put in main window or frame, not in canvas. If you use grid then you don't nee canvas.

Comment: now I see two problems - (1) you use `place()` to put `mFrame` so you have to use `place_forget()` to remove/hide it. But then you will have another problem (2) you have to create new mFrame for new buttons.

Comment: I just edit the code, {} didn't work probably so I did my best to correct indentations. I'm no longer using canvas

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: sorry, but how to create a new mFrame. can it be the same name or it should be different

Comment: it has to be the same name because you use the same name in `Button(mFrame)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I used this to remove old Frame with all buttons and to create new Frame for new buttons

```
def makegrid6():
    global mFrame

    mFrame.destroy()

    mFrame = tk.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 500, bg = "lightgrey")
    mFrame.place(x= 10, y = 10)

    makegrid66()
```

but it had one problem - new Frame was created on top of other widgets so then were hidden and unavaliable.

So I created `xFrame` in which I put `mFrame` and `xFrame` will be all time in window so it will be no moved on top of other widgets

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')

# parent `root` 
xFrame = tk.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 500, bg = "lightgrey")
xFrame.place(x= 10, y = 10)

# parent `xFrame`
mFrame = tk.Frame(xFrame, height = 500, width = 500, bg = "lightgrey")
mFrame.pack()
```

and then it show new frame behind `checkbox` and other buttons.

To put `mFrame` in `xFrame` I use `pack()` instead of `place()` because it doesn't neeed options and there will be no other widgets so there is no need to set `x,y`.

You said that you put `mFrame` in `Canvas` (but I don't see it in code) so you could use `Canvas` instead of `xFrame`.

---

BTW: There is suggestion to not use spaces around `=` inside functions.
See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

Here code with `xFrame`

I changed also `makegrid100()` to make it shorter and more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os
import time, sys
from time import sleep

# --- functions ---

def changecolo(i, j):
    if not ((i == 0 and j == 0) or (i == 12 and j == 12)):
        if mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].cget('bg') == 'black':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].configure(bg='white')
        elif mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].cget('bg') == 'white':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].configure(bg='grey')
        elif mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].cget('bg') == 'grey':
            mFrame.grid_slaves(row=i, column=j)[0].configure(bg='black')

def setalg():
    value = 6

def makegrid6():
    global mFrame # inform function to use external/global variable instead of locla one when it will assign value (`=`) 

    mFrame.destroy()

    mFrame = tk.Frame(xFrame, height=500, width=500, bg="lightgrey")
    mFrame.pack()

    makegrid66()

def makegrid66():

    for i in range(6):
        for j in range (6):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                grids6=tk.Button(mFrame, bg='blue', text=(5 - i) + (5 - j), state='disabled', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=11, height=5)
                grids6.grid(row=i, column=j)
            elif i == 5 and j == 5:
                grids6=tk.Button(mFrame, bg='red', text=(5 - i) + (5 - j) , state='disabled', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=11, height=5)
                grids6.grid(row=i, column=j)
            elif (((i == 0 or i == 1 or i == 2) and (j == 2)) or (i == 4 and j == 1)):
                grids6=tk.Button(mFrame, bg='white', text=(5 - i) + (5 - j) , highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=11, height=5, state='disabled')
                grids6.grid(row=i, column=j)
            elif (i == 3 and j == 2):
                grids6=tk.Button(mFrame, bg='grey', text=(5 - i) + (5 - j) , highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=11, height=5, state='disabled')
                grids6.grid(row=i, column=j)
            else:
                grids6=tk.Button(mFrame, bg='black', text=(5 - i) + (5 - j), fg='white', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=11, height=5, state='disabled')
                grids6.grid(row=i, column=j) 
    return mFrame.grid_slaves, i, j

def makegrid10():
    global mFrame # inform function to use external/global variable instead of locla one when it will assign value (`=`) 

    mFrame.destroy()

    mFrame = tk.Frame(xFrame, height=500, width=500, bg="lightgrey")
    mFrame.pack()

    makegrid100()

def makegrid100():

    for i in range(13):
        for j in range (13):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                bg_color = 'blue'
                state = 'disabled'
            elif i == 12 and j == 12:
                bg_color = 'red'
                state = 'disabled'
            else:
                bg_color = 'black'
                state = 'normal'

            b = tk.Button(mFrame, bg=bg_color, text=(12-i)+(12-j), state=state, fg='white', highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=4, height=2, command=lambda x=i, y=j: changecolo(x, y))
            b.grid(row=i, column=j)

    return mFrame.grid_slaves, i, j   

def play():
   if diffVar.get() == "sim":
       butons, l, k=makegrid66()
       Greedy(butons, l, k)
   else:
       butons, l, k=makegrid100()
       Greedy(butons, l, k)
def aStar():
   print(1000010)

def Greedy(butons, k, l):
    for i in range(k + 1):
        for j in range(l + 1):
            print(i, j)
            mini=butons(row=i, column=j)[0].cget('text')
            m, n=i, j
            if i - 1 > -1:
                if butons(row=i - 1, column=j)[0].cget('text') < mini:
                    mini=butons(row=i - 1, column=j)[0].cget('text')
                    m=i - 1
            if i + 1 < 6:
                if butons(row=i + 1, column=j)[0].cget('text') < mini:
                    mini=butons(row=i + 1, column=j)[0].cget('text')
                    m=i + 1
            if j - 1 > -1:
                if butons(row=i, column=j - 1)[0].cget('text') < mini:
                    mini=butons(row=i, column=j - 1)[0].cget('text')
                    n=j - 1
            if j + 1 < 6:
                if butons(row=i, column=j + 1)[0].cget('text') < mini:
                    mini=butons(row=i, column=j + 1)[0].cget('text')
                    n=j + 1
            i, j=m, n
            butons(row=m, column=n)[0].configure(bg='brown')

def UCS():
   print(99)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')

xFrame = tk.Frame(root, height=500, width=500, bg="lightgrey")
xFrame.place(x= 10, y=10)

mFrame = tk.Frame(xFrame, height=500, width=500, bg="lightgrey")
mFrame.pack()

diffVar = tk.StringVar()
dif = tk.Label(root, text="Problem Difficulty", bg="Lightgrey")
dif.place (x=550, y=30)

simp = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Simple", value="sim", bg="Lightgrey", variable=diffVar, command=makegrid6)
simp.place(x=550, y=60)
comp = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Complex", value="com", bg="Lightgrey", variable=diffVar, command=makegrid10)
comp.place(x=550, y=90)

algVar = tk.IntVar()
algVar.set(1)
dif = tk.Label(root, text="Choose an Algorithm", bg="Lightgrey")
dif.place (x=550, y=180)

alg1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="A*", value=1, bg="Lightgrey", variable=algVar, command=setalg)
alg1.place(x=550, y=210)
alg2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Greedy", value=2, bg="Lightgrey", variable=algVar, command=setalg)
alg2.place(x=550, y=240)
alg3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="UCS", value=3, bg="Lightgrey", variable=algVar, command=setalg)
alg3.place(x=550, y=270)

f2 = tk.Canvas(root, height=30, width=30, bg="White")

playbu = tk.Button(root, text="Play", bg="White", width=15, command=play)
playbu.place(x=10, y=550)

nextbu = tk.Button(root, text="Next", bg="White", width=15)
nextbu.place(x=140, y=550)

fasterbu = tk.Button(root, text="Faster", bg="White", width=15)
fasterbu.place(x=270, y=550)

resetbu = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", bg="White", width=15)
resetbu.place(x=400, y=550)

root.mainloop()
```